# How do I retrieve property a of Pulumi resource using python?

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, pulumi

I'm creating a GCP storage bucket and aggregated log sink using Pulumi and Python. To create the sink I need the value of the bucket id from Pulumi.

```
bucket = storage.Bucket(resource_name=bucket_name, 
                        location="us-central1", 
                        storage_class="REGIONAL",
                        uniform_bucket_level_access=True)

# destination value is needed to create the logging sink.
destination = Output.all(bucket.id).apply(lambda l: f"storage.googleapis.com/{l[0]}")

print(destination)
```

I would expect to get a print output of the destination variable similar to `"storage.googleapis.com/bucket_id"`. Instead I am getting
`<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x10c39ae80>`. I've also tried using the Pulumi concat method as described at the [Pulumi docs](https://www.pulumi.com/docs/intro/concepts/programming-model/#outputs).

```
destination = Output.concat("storage.googleapis.com/", bucket.id)

print(destination)
```

This returns the same `<pulumi.output.Output object at 0x10c39ae80>` instead of the expected string.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't print an `Output` because an output is a container for a deferred value that is not yet available when `print` is called. Instead, try exporting the value as a stack output

```
pulumi.export("destination", destination)
```

If you really want to print it, try doing so from within an `apply`:

```
destination.apply(lambda v: print(v))
```

By the way, your first snippet can be simplified to

```
destination = bucket.id.apply(lambda id: f"storage.googleapis.com/{id}")
```

but `concat` is even simpler indeed.

Comment: Thanks, That makes sense. What I can’t determine is how to build that destination string value as an input to the Organization Sink resource. The destination value is the string storage.googleapis.com/ along wire the bucket I’d.

Comment: For example, after creating the bucket I'm using 
```sink = logging.OrganizationSink("resource-ops-sink",
                        destination=f"storage.googleapis.com/{bucket.id}",
                        filter=filter,
                        org_id=org)```

I'm getting an error on the destination variable
```
gcp:logging:OrganizationSink (resource-ops-sink):
    error: 1 error occurred:
     * googleapi: Error 404: Bucket <pulumi.output.Output object at 0x10bcc16a0> does not exist, notFound
```

Comment: Use `destintion=Output.concat("storage.googleapis.com/", bucket.id)` instead of direct string formatting